# Print function won't print the complete list before moving on

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to print out a list of links for a results page and then call the `scraper` function on itself while adding 1 to the variable `pageNum`. For some reason, this code only prints out the first result on each page instead of printing all results and then moving on to the following page. How do I wait for my print function to finish completely before recursively calling the `scraper` function

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


def scraper(pageNum):
        req = Request("http://www.someurl.com/Search/page="+str(pageNum)+"&facet_Category=20", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
        html = urlopen(req).read()
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
        for result in bsObj.select("h2 a"):
            print(result["href"])
            scraper(pageNum+1)


scraper(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does that because you recursively call `scraper` within the loop, so the recursion happens as soon as you print the first link.

You can fix this by moving the recursive call back one indent, but note that recursion is not really a good solution to this sort of problem - you should really just use a nested loop. (Apart from anything else, you don't seem to have a base case so your recursion will never end.)

```
def scraper(pageNum):
    while pageNum < SOME_TARGET_VALUE:
        req = Request("http://www.someurl.com/Search/page="+str(pageNum)+"&facet_Category=20", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
        html = urlopen(req).read()
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
        for result in bsObj.select("h2 a"):
            print(result["href"])
        pageNum += 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate it, I will look at using a nested loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it appears that you are calling scraper function within the for loop for printing links. Just move it outside the for loop and that should work.

```
def scraper(pageNum):
    req = Request("http://www.someurl.com/Search/page="+str(pageNum)+"&facet_Category=20", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    html = urlopen(req).read()
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for result in bsObj.select("h2 a"):
        print(result["href"])
    scraper(pageNum+1)
```